# What is the meaning of the word "Boolean" as it relates to computers?

Tags: programming-languages, terminology, boolean

Is it related to hardware or software or both?

Is it a logic or name of function or data types?

**Off topic**

What does the word "Boolean" mean in the English language?

---

**Edit:** I have read the page on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean) but it has many links related to this term. I wanted to ask on SO to get a programmers view.

Comment: I question the authenticity of this question.  If you're on SO and don't know what Boolean is...snookie.

Comment: I fail to see how something so general would be any different.  What part didn't you understand on the Wikipedia page, was it the "[named after George Boole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole)" or "[Boolean data type, a certain datatype in computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type)"?  Sorry I came back to this and you did good at letting this get by Jitendra :)  Something like this normally doesn't stay open for long.  I know, I've tried ha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a value type named after [George Boole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole), a mathematician from the 1800's.  A boolean value is either true or false.  At the hardware level, everything is boolean (0's and 1's).  At the software level, boolean values are used anywhere logic needs to be performed -- statements such as if, while and for all evaluate boolean expressions to see if they should be performed.

Comment: Actually, Boolean is not `0s` and `1s`, it's `0` and not `0`.  This is especially important in multi-state hardware that measures 0s, 1s, and states in between.  `0` and `1` represent the crest and the trough of an electrical sin wave.  Engineers found that they could also use the inflection point as well as other points to record partial bits.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to hardware, in that the little hardware switches that represent bits in computers are either on or off (i.e., ground voltage level or a small positive voltage level indicating the 1 bit). Also, in programming, the boolean type represents a true or false value and most strongly typed languages support this type.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean means a value that can be either True or False, or any other binary representation of true and false.  It's named for George Boole, an English mathematician who first explored the mathematics of pure true and false values.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a word for true/false (on/off) type logic and data.

It is used both in hardware (for example - on may be defined as about 5 Volts, off as less then that) and for software.

It is both used for a type of logic (boolean logic) and for data types that hold only two states.

It is named after [George Boole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole) who invented the logic.

Comment: "It is simply a word for true/false (on/off)" so is it a simplest logic in programming ever?